# Ring.util.response/redirect does not redirect site

Tags: redirect, clojure, http-redirect, compojure, ring

I have a master page that displays the navbar, and copyright information, as well as handling logins. It gets the user profile, and passes it to the content function, or nil if the user is not signed in. So, for pages that I'd like to require sign in, I am going to have a check at the top, and redirect if the user is not signed in. The namespace declaration includes

```
(ns kandj.views.content
  (:require [ring.util.response :as response]))
```

For the content function, I have the following code:

```
(defn profile [g-profile]
  (if (nil? g-profile)
    (do (response/redirect "/" 307)
        (println "redirecting"))))
```

It prints `redirecting` to the console, but it does not actually redirect. I have variously tried using a string for the redirect code `"307"`, and excluding it to use the default of 302. Nothing I have tried causes the page to redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have your `response/redirect` as the last expression otherwise your handler returns `nil` which is the result of `println` expression.

However, I think you should handle such cross-cutting concerns systematically instead of adding security related logic to each of your pages. The idiomatic approach is to use ring's middleware.

You could write your own middleware handler which would know if the requested URL requires the user to be authenticated or not and pass through to the page render or redirect to the login page.

For example:

```
(defn authenticated? [request]
  ... your logic to check if the user is authenticated or not...)

(defn secured-url? [request]
  ... your logic for determining if the requested page requires authenticated user...)

(defn wrap-user-auth-check [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (if (and (secured-url? request)
             (authenticated? request))
      (handler request)
      (response/redirect "/"))))

(def app
  (-> handler
    (wrap-user-auth-check)))
```

You might also take a look at a library for handling web app security for ring: [friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend).

Comment: Oh. Is there any way to have it bubble up, and be the only thing returned? I'm using hiccup for templating. After removing the `println`, I get `<div id="content">{:status 302, :headers {"Location" "/"}, :body ""}</div>` as a result of the other code. How is this usually done?

Comment: I've solved the problem, but it is less than ideal if there is a standard way to do it. As far as I can tell, there's no `return` function. Which seems like it would be best way to handle this situation

Comment: I have enhanced my answer with more info how to handle such cases in your web app.

Comment: Regarding the `return` function: there is no such construct in Clojure. Instead each every form in Clojure is an expression and has a return value. So in your case the logic should be `(if (some-condition) (response/redirect "/") (render-page))`

Comment: Thanks! That makes way more sense

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [compojure-api](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api)  This is how you implement the redirection on your endpoint:

1. requrie this on handler [ring.util.response :refer [redirect]]
2. code for endpoint
   (GET "/confrimemail" []
      (redirect "http://www.zeetomic.com"))